# How to center a video vertically

Tags: html, css

I have my video within a div tag, 
I center it horizontally to the window with

```
    .center { margin: 0 auto; width: 720px; height: 480px; }
```

I've been trying to center it vertically to the window with

```
   .center { margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 720px; height: 480px; }
```

and it doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Vertically to what? The window? Also, it's `height: 480px`.

Comment: `height=480px; != height: 480px;` Also some html and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be nice.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, typed it wrong

Comment: and vertically/horizontally to the window

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsfiddle ? A mistake doesnt appear in your code.

Comment: See my answer below. For reference, `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` is the same as writing `margin: 0 auto`. The latter is simply shorthand for setting the top and bottom, and left and right margins.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily using absolute positioning. For example (will center it to the container):

```
.center { 
    width: 720px; 
    height: 480px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -240px 0 0 -360px;
}
```

Basically, you assign it to be 50% from the top left of the container, and then specify negative margins which are half the height and width respectively.

Please see this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/USz6g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are to use `absolute` a common practice is:

```
.center { 
    width: 720px; 
    height: 480px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will center it to its container.